# How to pass value from table to ajax function in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm listing all users identity names in my Asp.net MVC

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.UserName</td>
                <td>   <input type="button" id="show" class="show"  value="Show Roles" /></td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

I want to show user details using ajax when button show been clicked

For this I added div to display data in the same view;

```
<div id="target">Trigger</div>
```

and ajax get the details from the action control

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: { UserName:'xxxxxxx'},
            url: '@Url.Action("DisplyRoles","Admin")',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#target").html(result);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error");

            }
        });

    });
  });
```

My question:
What to put instead of **xxxxxx** as I want to pass current user name which is in the same row of **show** button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `data-` attribute in the `<button>`. Note also that you should remove the `id` attribute (duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html)

```
<input type="button" data-username="@item.UserName" class="show"  value="Show Roles" />
```

and then access it in the script

```
$('.show').click(function () {
    var name = $(this).data('username');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { UserName: name },
        url: '@Url.Action("DisplyRoles","Admin")',
        success: function (result) {
```

You could also access it by reading the value from the previous `<td>` element

```
var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
```

Comment: Yes exactly, it's work perfect. I prefer data- attribute . it's very logically. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's possible to use data-userID or data-anyName rather than data-username ?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever you want

Comment: But note it should always be lower case (as defined by the standards)